# Android java.lang.RuntimeException LocationManager

Tags: java, android, cordova, locationmanager

I am trying to use LocationManager to get the latitude,longitude, etc. Now when I am running the code with the LocationManager the below error is occurring.

```
02-17 09:31:10.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-17 09:31:10.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{     com.example.testphonegap/com.example.testphonegap.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid provider: null
02-17 09:31:10.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
02-17 09:31:10.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-17 09:31:10.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-17 09:31:10.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-17 09:31:10.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-17 09:31:10.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-17 09:31:10.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
02-17 09:31:10.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-17 09:31:10.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-17 09:31:10.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-17 09:31:10.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-17 09:31:10.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-17 09:31:10.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid provider: null
02-17 09:31:10.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at android.location.LocationManager.checkProvider(LocationManager.java:1594)
02-17 09:31:10.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:425)
02-17 09:31:10.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at com.example.testphonegap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:93)
02-17 09:31:10.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
02-17 09:31:10.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
02-17 09:31:10.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
```

My Code is as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();

        // new code
        super.setBooleanProperty("keepRunning", true);

        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.ldpi);
        super.setStringProperty("loadingDialog", "Loading Silver Angel ...");

        appView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "MainActivity");

        super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 50000); 
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html",50000);

        // New Code
       LocationManager locationManager;
       String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
       locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(context);

       Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
       criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
       criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
       criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
       criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
       criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
       String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

       updateWithNewLocation(null);

       locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, (10*60*1000), 10, locationListener);    

    }

    public void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) {

        if (location != null) {

            counter++;
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();

            //current speed fo the gps device
            currentSpeed = round(location.getSpeed(),3,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
            kmphSpeed = round((currentSpeed*3.6),3,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);

            //all speeds added together
            totalSpeed = totalSpeed + currentSpeed;
            totalKmph = totalKmph + kmphSpeed;

            //calculates average speed
            avgSpeed = round(totalSpeed/counter,3,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
            avgKmph = round(totalKmph/counter,3,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
        } 
    }

    // new Code
    private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
          updateWithNewLocation(location);
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
          updateWithNewLocation(null);
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){ }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, 
                                    Bundle extras){ }
    };


}
```

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong please? Do I need to use Looper? If yes where do I need to put it?

Thanks & Regards,

Keith Spiteri

Comment: post your 93 line in `com.example.testphonegap.MainActivity.onCreate() method`.

Comment: I guess provider is null (end of onCreate())

Comment: Wild guess, your logcat says the provider is `null`; I'd say `provider` is null.

Comment: what line are you referring please?

Comment: Are you referring to locationListener? I have this line: private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener(). Isn't that creating a new instance? Also at all, that error is taken from log cat.

Comment: @BenvanGompel What do you mean  by provider please?

Comment: @keithSpiteri: String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

Answer (score 0):

As per your logcat output, you are providing null provider to location manager.

Use below code to getProvider and set it with location manager.

```
         locationManager = (LocationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Service.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        // ///Criteria //////////

        crta = new Criteria();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
            crta.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        }else{
            crta.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_MEDIUM);
        }
        crta.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(crta, true);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,
                    (10*60*1000), 10, YOUR_LOCATION_LISTENER);
```

Put this code into try catch block.